# Complex partial string matching in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string-matching, partial-matches

Given a dataframe with the following structure and values `json_path` -

| json_path | Reporting Group | Entity/Grouping |
| --- | --- | --- |
| data.attributes.total.children.[0] | Christian Family | Abraham Family |
| data.attributes.total.children.[0].children.[0] | Christian Family | In Estate |
| data.attributes.total.children.[0].children.[0].children.[0].children.[0] | Christian Family | Cash |
| data.attributes.total.children.[0].children.[0].children.[1].children.[0] | Christian Family | Investment Grade Fixed Income |

How would I filter on the `json_path` rows which contain`children` four times? i.e., I want to filter on index position 2-3 -

| **json_path** | **Reporting Group** | **Entity/Grouping** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| data.attributes.total.children.[0].children.[0].children.[0].children.[0] | Christian Family | Cash |
| data.attributes.total.children.[0].children.[0].children.[1].children.[0] | Christian Family | Investment Grade Fixed Income |

I know how to obtain a partial match, however the integers in the square brackets will be inconsistent, so my instinct is telling me to somehow have logic that counts the instances of `children` (i.e., `children` appearing 4x) and using that as a basis to filter.

Any suggestions or resources on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, a naive approach would be to count the occurrence of `.children` and compare the count with 4 to create boolean mask which can be used to filter the rows

```
df[df['json_path'].str.count(r'\.children').eq(4)]
```

A more robust approach would be to check for the consecutive occurrence of 4 children

```
df[df['json_path'].str.contains(r'(\.children\.\[\d+\]){4}')]
```

---

```
                                                                   json_path   Reporting Group                Entity/Grouping
2  data.attributes.total.children.[0].children.[0].children.[0].children.[0]  Christian Family                           Cash
3  data.attributes.total.children.[0].children.[0].children.[1].children.[0]  Christian Family  Investment Grade Fixed Income
```